# Object oriented python constructor and class methods

Tags: python, class, methods

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class SportsCar(object):

        def __init__(self,make,colour):
                self.make = make
                self.colour = colour
                self.horn = "BEEEEEEEEPPPPPPP"

        def honk(self):
                #now we can make some noise!
                print self.make,'  ',self.colour,'  ',self.horn
                print "Done "


mycar = SportsCar('Honda','silver')
#print mycar.make 
#print mycar.colour

print mycar.honk()


print "Good Bye!!"
```

The output of the above code is given below.

```
Honda    silver    BEEEEEEEEPPPPPPP
Done 
None
Good Bye!!
```

The first two lines of the output

```
Honda    silver    BEEEEEEEEPPPPPPP
Done
```

This is printed by mycar.honk().

I also understand the 4th line

```
Good Bye!!
```

I don't understand from where 'None' in the third line come from? Can someone please explain?

Also another related question

what is the difference between the declerations

```
class SportsCar:
```

and

```
class SportsCar(object):
```

I have been seeing both the declerations in different places.?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functions *always* have a return value, `None` by default.

You are printing the return value of the `.honk()` method, which is the default `None`:

```
print mycar.honk()
```

You can just call `mycar.honk()` *without* the `print` statement. The method does it's own printing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything in your honk method, therefore it returns None by default.